# React Native function calls not working – can’t find `this.function2`

Tags: javascript, function, react-native

I cannot get this working.  It might be simple but there is just no information online that works.

Here is what I am trying to do.

```
class Test {
  componentDidMount() {
      this.function1();
  }      

  function1() {
     var myListener = listener.on(something) {
         console.log('function1 triggered');
         key = 'djh3489739082';
         name = 'gary';
         email = 'gary@email.com';
         this.function2(key, name, email);
     }
  }

  function2 = ({ key, name, email }) => {
     console.log('key: ' + key);
     console.log('name: ' + name);
     console.log('email: ' + email);
  }
}
```

That's basically it.  The error I get in the console is that it can't find variable `this.function2`.

It doesn't work when I try removing the `this.` prefix.  I also have a much simpler function call in my code that works fine like this:

```
  function3() {
     // Some code here
     this.function4();
  }

  function4() {
     // Do some things.
  }
```

And `function3` calls `function4` without issue.  It's just because I need to pass parameters that it falls over and like NO ONE online needs to do this, apparently.  The only examples I have found use `const` before the function.  So like:

```
const function2 = ({ parameter1, parameter2, parameter3 }) => {
```

But this immediately throws an error.  I can't use `const` or `var` or any of that stuff.

This should be easy, surely!  Any ideas?

Comment: Depending on how you call `function1`, the value of `this` inside it can be set differently. So we can't give a full explanation until you show that calling code. [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) can be unintuitive in JavaScript; you should read about it.

Comment: Also, you wrote `Class`, but your original code has `class`, right?

Comment: Sorry, yes the original code has "class".  With regards to the rest, that is literally the whole lot.   Are you suggesting that one of the paramaters I am passing is incorrect?  Because the error seems to be saying that it has no visibility of the function at all.

Comment: I have updated the code above to show you what I am trying to do.  It is very basic, but I just can't get the compiler to recognise the function.

Comment: This can't be your whole code, because you didn't include any code that calls `function1`. You couldn't get any error about `this.function2` not existing unless `function1` were being run, because the body of `function1` is where `this.function2` is referenced. Just defining a class will not run it, and you only posted the class definition. What is your code that does `var foo = new Test()` and `foo.function1()`, or however `function1` gets called?

Comment: I have updated it again for you.   I have code at componentDidMount() that triggers when the screen is loaded.   It goes through and then jumps to function1, it works perfectly fine.    function1 runs through perfectly fine and all my console logs trigger.   Everything is perfect right up to the point where I call function2.    It just can't see it.

Comment: I don't see the problem in the code you posted, but maybe you'll find it yourself if I summarize how `this` works. `this` is a hidden parameter, passed in when you call `function1` – it is not set when you define `function1`. Example: `var aTest = new Test(); aTest.function1();` will work – `this` will be `aTest`, which was written before the `.` in the function call. But if you then did `var copyOfFunc1 = aTest.function1; copyOfFunc1();`, you will get the error you are seeing. There is no `foo.` before `copyOfFunc1()`, so `this` inside it will be `undefined`.

Comment: @RoryO'Kane There actually is a problem in his code, but it's pretty silly haha, check the answer I posted

Comment: Rory can you post an answer so I can accept it?   When you kept asking for my code you forced me to look closer at it, because I couldn't see how it was different to what I was posting.  I was actually calling "this." from inside a listener, so "this" wasn't referencing the right thing.  I managed to get it working by putting the function2 function inside the same function as this listener.   That was a very silly thing to do and I can only apologise.  Post an answer of some kind so I can accept it Rory.  You got me there.

Comment: I also updated the original question to include this new find, so it makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what's wrong in your code. How many parameters does your `function2` take? **One**, not three, but one. It takes a JSON object as a parameter, who has 3 properties: `key`, `name` and `email`, because you wrapped them with `{}`, but when you call it in `function1`, you passed 3 parameters to it, without the `{}`, which makes it not a JSON object.

So, you can either:

```
// Don't modify function2 but change function1 like so
function1() {
    this.function2({ key, name, email })
}
```

or

```
// Don't modify function1 but change function2 like so
function2(key, name, email) {

}
```

Comment: That’s a good catch, but this problem wouldn’t explain the error “that it can't find variable `this.function2`” that OP describes. In fact, if they passed a string as the first parameter that is destructured, no error would be thrown – `'myKey'.email` and so on just return `undefined`. So OP still has another error to fix after fixing this.